# Открыть веб сервер запущенный в docker

Tags: python, docker, flask

Я создал образ который запускаю таким вот образом

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash  docker-whale
```

В в самом докер контейнере я запускаю свой веб сервер написанный на python

```
python3 test.py
```

Пишет, что запустилось на ip 127.0.0.1:5000

Как теперь я могу получить доступ к своей странице через основную машину?
Переходя по ссылке 127.0.0.1:5000 страница не открывается

Comment: `127.0.0.1` внутренний адрес машины и доступен внутри машины, но не в сети, и думаю для докера это правило сохраняется. Попробуйте запустить на `0.0.0.0` и подключаться по локальному ip

Comment: ему выдается ip 172.17.0.5 который не в одной сети с моим ПК

Comment: Пробросьте порт из контейнера наружу https://www.whitesourcesoftware.com/free-developer-tools/blog/docker-expose-port/

Comment: `docker run -it -p 192.168.0.102:8084:5000 docker-whale` ошибка:
`C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint thirsty_diffie (6ee54c445b567633c8765d1790f06e2e80e8606f641cf8b7e717e44107df3f4d): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 192.168.0.102:8084: bind: cannot assign requested address.`

Comment: `-p 127.0.0.1:5555:5000`, и подключайтесь к `http://127.0.0.1:5555`

Comment: пробовал, все равно не открывает страницу, уже попробовал apache установить и пробросить на 80й порт, тоже не открывает

Answer (score -1):

docker run -p 5000: 5000 -it --entrypoint /bin/bash  docker-whale